# Wordpress menu shows max 5 items

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a custum menu in Wordpress, but it show only max 5 items, but in this case there are 8 items to show.

How can i fix this?

[image]

```
                    <?php $terms = get_terms($taxonomyName, array('parent' => $pterm->term_id, 'orderby' => 'slug',  'posts_per_page'=>-1,  'hide_empty' => false));
                    foreach ($terms as $term) { ?>
                   <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ); ?>"><?php echo  $term->name ; ?></a>
                   <div class="post">

                   <ul class="childpost">
                   <?php $wpq = array ('taxonomy'=>'type','term'=>$term->slug);
                         $myquery = new WP_Query ($wpq); ?>

                        <?php while ($myquery->have_posts()) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>

                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
                    <div class="image"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('product'); ?></a></div></li>
                        <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: show of your `admin dashboard menu ` screen.

Comment: I post the code of the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your Settings under WordPress admin. You most probably have 'max blog posts to show' set to 5. Increase this to a number of your liking.

Comment: Sometimes the answer is so simple! Thank you